# Overlay one div over other div without space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I would like to place a div element with the bottom half over an other div element. You can see a simple markup [**here**](https://www.bootply.com/MwiGDu8ECl)

If you enable the `transform` property for .overlay then the element is pushed half way down  but also the white space of the parent container is visible. Is there any chance to avoid this and get a solution without any space before the dark-gray div? I also would like to avoid to set a negative margin-top if perhaps there is a better solution.

This markup isnt fix, it can be changed if it is necessary.

```css
.overlay {
  height: 200px;
  //transform: translateY(50%);
}

.overlay .col {
  background: #333;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incin proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incin proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row overlay no-gutters">
      <div class="col col-12 mx-auto">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1 mx-auto">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should rephrase your question, it is very difficult to understand what you actually want. maybe draw a sketch? if you just want a div after your paragraph, you could just do <div style='height:100px; overflow:hidden;'>text content<div class='gray' style='height:100%; background-color:silver;'></div></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way besides negative margin I can think of is to use a pseudo ::after element on the `.col`...

https://www.bootply.com/Ukc9jdDGnM

```
.overlay .col::after {
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear, what the question is.
But if the previous answer is correct, then all I did is just add `height` to `.overlay .col`

```
.overlay .col {
  background: #333;
  height:300px;
}
```

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.overlay {
  height: 200px;
  //transform: translateY(50%);
}

.overlay .col {
  background: #333;
  height: 300px;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incin proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incin proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row overlay no-gutters">
      <div class="col col-12 mx-auto">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mx-auto">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```